# Paraphrase "Her cooking is not so good."

Tags: phrase-request, paraphrasing

Let's assume following situation. You've been invited to a dinner by friend of yours. He told you that his wife is a great cook. After you got home, you say (in a private conversation) to your partner:

> Frankly speaking, her cooking is not so good.

This isn't worded well. How could I rephrase the sentence to sound more natural?

Comment: The present phrasing is not so good?

Comment: *"Frankly speaking, she's not a good cook."* Or *"Frankly speaking, her cooking wasn't good."*

Comment: Please explain why you think your initial statement isn't worded well.

Comment: If you're talking to *your* partner, perhaps you want "Honey, I'll take your cooking any day." and wink. =)

Comment: @corsiKa +1 for great sense of humor)

Answer (score 10):

I'm not clear exactly why OP thinks his version "isn't worded well". It's perfectly natural English - though it may be worth noting that most native speakers would change at least the first two words...

[image: chart]

Other possible changes would be ***isn't*** rather than ***is not***, and ***hot*** rather than ***good***. But these are just slightly more informal versions of OP's original - since we know the context is *very* informal, they're obviously "acceptable", but I see no reason to actually *prefer* either of these changes.

---

But I would also point out that (particularly in relaxed informal contexts), I'd be reasonably certain<sup>1</sup> an even more common alternative to the first two words would be...

> ***To be honest***, her cooking was not so good
>    *...wasn't all that hot*
>    *...wasn't up to much*
>    *...was no great shakes*
>    etc., etc. (there are any number of idiomatic alternatives here, but they're not "better")

---

Regarding the verb form, it's a very fine point. Arguably you'd be more likely to use present tense *(**is** not so good)* if you think it's likely you and/or your partner will have future encounters with the friend's wife's lacklustre cooking (in which case it's more of an *ongoing, still relevant* situation).

But since you're only referring to her lack of culinary skills because of that earlier meal, I think you'd actually be more likely to use past tense *(**wasn't** anything to write home about, **was** a bit of a letdown)*.

---

<sup>1</sup> [This NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to%20be%20honest%20I%20do%2Cto%20be%20frank%20I%20do&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20be%20honest%20I%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20be%20frank%20I%20do%3B%2Cc0) strongly suggests my gut feeling re relative prevalence is correct.

Comment: I agree that the original phrasing is fine and offer one more alternative _"Honestly, her cooking wasn't that great."_

Comment: Of all the options you offer here, the one I prefer most is "...wasn't all that hot," because it forms such a nice culinary pun. As for her hot air baloon piloting skills, well, those were a bit of a letdown. :^)

Comment: I was born in England and raised in Canada, and frankly speaking, my first choice of how to say that would be exactly as the OP posted.

Comment: yeah, I agree with OP. I would tend to elide "cooking is" to "cooking's" rather than elide "is not" to "isn't" although i'm not sure why

Answer (score 3):

I'd argue that it's actually slightly awkward to talk about someone's "cooking".  One would generally talk about her skill at the role of being "a cook".

And echoing @FumbleFingers, "frankness" is a bit of an awkward word.  It's best known from [Gone With The Wind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankly,_my_dear,_I_don't_give_a_damn) and rarely used outside of that; and it also is used in jokes that play on the idea of someone being named Frank vs. speaking with candor.

*(Candor is also an "infrequently used word" :-P)*

So most natural if you want to speak in broad strokes about someone's kitchen skills, you might say:

> To be honest, she isn't a very good cook.

Referring to a single meal you've had as someone's "cooking" is fine, but still probably better to talk about the precise dish.

> Honestly, that chicken casserole she made tasted terrible.

Or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

- **Tell you the truth**, her cooking wasn't that good.
- **To be honest**, I didn't like the food that much.
- **In all honesty**, her cooking wasn't that great.
- **In all frankness**, her cooking wasn't up to scratch.
- **Frankly**, it (the meal) was rather disappointing

in the last example, I would omit "speaking". The term, [frankly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/frankly), expresses the desire to be truthful; *brutally honest*; [*totally frank*](https://www.google.com/search?q=absolutely%20frank&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&oq=absolutely%20frank&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22totally%20frank%22&tbm=bks&start=10); and  [*to be blunt*](https://www.google.com/search?q=absolutely%20frank&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&oq=absolutely%20frank&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22to%20be%20blunt%22&tbm=bks&start=10).

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/frankly) defines *frankly* as

> **frankly** (ˈfræŋklɪ)
>   *adv*
>   1. (sentence modifier) in truth; to be honest: *frankly, I can't bear him*.
>   2. in a frank manner

Answer (score 2):

> Frankly speaking, her cooking is not so good.

This is fine, just a little stilted.  Most people when speaking would say "isn't" rather than "is not", unless being emphatic (in which case, there'd be a strong stress on "not").  "Frankly speaking" is somewhat redundant when you're speaking: it's obvious that you don't mean "frankly writing" or "frankly communicating telepathically" so just "frankly" would be more natural.  (Arguably, even "frankly" is redundant: why would you speak anything but frankly with your partner, in private, when it's your friend who disappointed you, rather than your partner's? But that's probably taking things to extremes.)

Answer (score 0):

Given baseline = "wife is a great cook"

Well, the above answers range in magnitude as such:

We see things such as "didn't live up to my expectations", which implies that while she may be a fine cook, it's not quite up to the "great" level.

And we also see things along the lines of "she isn't a very good cook", which implies that her cooking is far below great. Not even 'acceptable'.

So keep in mind that since you want to convey that her cooking is not great, knowing where her cooking skills do fall is helpful in figuring out the wording.